# How to color code (x,y)-coordinate points in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am given a bunch of x,y-coordinates. I want to plot these coordinates, but depending on their values, I want to give them a different color.

Apparently, this can easily be done by providing the `cmap` parameter to pyplot's scatter function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
data = rng.randn(500,2)
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], s=20, c=data[:,0], cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

This code snippet does not perform the way I want it to, though: The code I have provided will colorize points according to their position along the x-axis only. I want a color code that takes both x- and y-coordinates into account. Points located at the top left corner of my figure are suppossed to look alike. But they are also suppossed to look different from points in the bottom left corner.

I hope I have made my question a bit clearer. Thx for any help!

Comment: Can you share some sample data and a mock up of what you want. This is trivial to do with matplotlib's basic `scatter` function, maybe give it a try first and add your attempt to your question.

Comment: Do you have a specific GUI library you are using, such as tkinter?

Comment: @Dan there's a "matplotlib" tag in the question

Comment: Do you consider other packages such as `pandas`?

Comment: @Dan: I have rephrased my question to make it a bit clearer. It might still be a trivial task, but I am having a really hard time to understand what would be a good choice for `c`

Comment: You can use `color` argument in your scatter. You just have to define the color number for every point.

Comment: @Luk thanks, it's much easier to answer now. Are you looking for 4 distinct colours, 1 per quadrant? Or a smooth transition of colours that changes in both the x and y direction?

Comment: @Dan: A smooth transition would be amazing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot each quadrant in a different colour, you need to somehow map your data into 4 different numbers, 1 per quadrant. Here is a crude way to do this:

```
quadrant = (data[:, 0] > 0).astype(int) + 2 * (data[:, 1] > 0).astype(int)
```

now call

```
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], s=20, c=quadrant, cmap='jet')
```

[image]

note if this is what you wanted, you might prefer a [qualitative colormap](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative) over `jet`

if you want a smooth transition, you would need to map each of your dimensions to an orthogonal colour dimension. Here is how to do it in the RGB colour space, but this will look a bit ugly:

```
def normalize(arr):
    arr_min = np.min(arr)
    arr_max = np.max(arr)
    return (arr - arr_min) / (arr_max - arr_min)

red = normalize(data[:, 0])
green  = normalize(data[:, 1])
blue = np.zeros_like(red)
rgb = np.vstack((red, green, blue)).T
rgb = np.vstack((red, green, blue)).T
```

[image]

Now we have mapped red on the x-axis and green on the y-axis. So a point in the upper right is yellow as it has max red and green.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! ... so, I'm wondering. What if I want a specific colormap? Such as 'viridis' ? There must be a way to convert the np-array that contains the rgb-values into the corresponding values of 'viridis' ... I have found a few examples using images, but they rely on image-processing libraries.

Comment: Luk Viridis etc are 1D colourmaps. If you really wanted to take in account both dimensions and have the colours be meaningful then you can't do it. If you want the colourmap to go in just one direction (for example the first principle component) then you need to map your data down to 1D and use that. A simple 1D mapping woul just be `c=data[:, 0] + data[:, 1]` for example. The advantage of what I've shown hear is that if you had data i the bottom right, it would have been red. If you had data in the top left it would have been green. The colourmap has meaning in both your dimensions.

Comment: hmm... ok, I see. Thx again, Dan!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `c` parameter, e.g.:

```py
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=np.abs(data[:,0]))
```

You can also use e.g. `c=data[:,0]**2+data[:,1]**2`.

Comment: thx, @rpoleski! ... seems to work nicely. But how did you come up with this particular choice for `c` ?

Comment: Hard question. I just know some math. One more you may want to try is `np.abs(data[:,0])+np.abs(data[:,1])`.